# DefaultHttpClient is decrepated em Android app

Tags: android, http, app, deprecated

Estou realizando uma integração com um JSON no meu aplicativo, porém quando utilizo o `DefaultHttpClient`apresenta a mensagem:

> 'org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient' is deprecated.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
public class JsonClass {

    InputStream input = null;
    JSONObject jObect = null;
    String json = "";

    //Recebe sua url
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

        //HTTP request
        try {
            // default HttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            input = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    input, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            input.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.i("JRF", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Transforma a String de resposta em um JSonObject
        try {
            jObect = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // retorna o objeto
        return jObect;

    }
}
```

Em algumas classes como o `DefaultHttpClient`, `HttpPost`, `HttpResponse` e etc, aparecem riscado no código, e apresentam essa mensagem.

Comment: Sim é correto o que diz, então qual é sua pergunta?

Comment: Na verdade queria saber porque isso ocorre, se acarreta no projeto, pois apresenta erro ao tentar executar o projeto com a classe acima.

Comment: A Google recomenda que seja utilizada a classe [`HttpURLConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) em substituição da `DefaultHttpClient` a partir do android *Gingerbread* como se pode ler neste [post](http://android-developers.blogspot.pt/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html). No entanto nada o impede de continuar a usar a classe `DefaultHttpClient`.