# Qual a melhor forma de fazer uma requisição HTTP no Android?

Tags: java, android, json

Estou utilizando `DefaultHttpClient` para fazer requisições em json de um Webservice, porém esta função está obsoleta, qual a melhor alternativa para a criação de um cliente para Webservice?

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nesta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61241/defaulthttpclient-is-decrepated-em-android-app), mesmo nos comentários o *ramaral* responde essa mesma pergunta e indica a alternativa.

Answer (score 2):

Utlize HttpClient. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
package com.hostingcompass.web.controller;

import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;

public class WebCrawler {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://mkyong.com");
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        //...

    }

}
```

Não é necessário fechar a conexão.

Comment: Caso a resposta esteja correta, por favor faça um "tick" na seta verde na resposta.